# Ionic navbar <ion-buttons end> show icons vertically in android kitkat 4.4.4

Tags: css, ionic-framework

In the browser with ionic serve it shows well. But in the android kitkat device 4.4.4 the buttons on the right (end) of the navbar are displayed vertically and not horizontally.

```
<ion-navbar>
  <ion-title>AppTitle</ion-title>
  <ion-buttons end>
    <button ion-button icon-only>
      <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <button ion-button icon-only>
      <ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon>
    </button>
</ion-buttons>
```

Comment: If it's solved, please don't edit the title to add (SOLVED), instead, if you can, post an answer to your question (Yes, you can answer your own question), so that future visitors can see this question and the solution, and it would be helpful for them.

Comment: For a reason that I don't know, the <ion-buttons> tag assigns a width smaller than the size of the two buttons, so it aligns them vertically.

The solution I found is to assign a fixed width greater than the width of the two buttons. Example: <ion-buttons style = "width: 80px! Important;"> (placing the style in a class is a best practice).

regards

Comment: Ok sorry Madara Uchiha, this is my first collaboration in stackoverflow and I did not know how to do it correctly. I just wanted to share the solution I had found.
Thanks for clarification.

Comment: Actually, the correct way is to post a real answer (This is a comment), Press [this button](https://i.imgur.com/BSMzTqs.png) and write your answer there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a reason that I don't know, the  tag assigns a width smaller than the size of the two buttons, so it aligns them vertically. The solution I found is to assign a fixed width greater than the width of the two buttons. Example:  (placing the style in a class is a best practice)

Complete code:

```
<ion-navbar>
  <ion-title>AppTitle</ion-title>
  <ion-buttons end style="width: 80px! Important;">
    <button ion-button icon-only>
      <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <button ion-button icon-only>
      <ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is an example header that will have both buttons on the left and right positioned properly.

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
      <button ion-button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      <ion-title>Page Title</ion-title>
      <ion-buttons end>
        <button ion-button icon-only>
          <ion-icon ios="ios-cog" md="md-cog"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-buttons>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```